# How can I create a Measurement with Cumulocity REST?

Tags: c#, microservices, cumulocity

I am new to Cumulocity and trying to write a microservice for Cumulocity platform in C#.

I cloned Cumulocity.SDK.Client REST examples from here:
https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-sdk-cs/src/master/

I created some devices through InventoryApi and added some attributes at the creation(c8y_Hardware, c8y_RequiredAvailability, c8y_Position).
When I try to add a measurement to the device I am lost.

I tried adding measurement as an attribute.

My code looks like this:

```
 MeasurementRepresentation measurement = new MeasurementRepresentation();

 measurement.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
 measurement.Source = InventoryAPI.Get(new GId(deviceId));
 measurement.Type = "Temperature";

 JObject T = new JObject();
 T.Add("value", 90);
 T.Add("unit","C");
 measurement.Attrs.Add("Temperature", T);

 MeasurementApi.Create(measurement);
```

With this, I want a Temperature type measurement for the device. It doesn't throw an error but It also doesn't create any measurement.

First I thought I was wrong with Json nesting so added one more layer under attribute before "T".

Like this:

```
 JObject T = new JObject();
 T.Add("value", 90);
 T.Add("unit","C");

 JObject temperatureMeasurement = new JObject();
 temperatureMeasurement.Add("T",T);

 measurement.Attrs.Add("Temperature", temperatureMeasurement);
```

This too didn't work.

When I looked at test files, I saw some Set() method being used. Should I create a measurement object and then pass it with Set() method?

Since the Fragment classes in the test files are empty I don't know how the object should look.

Am I completely off or just some minor thing that I miss?

What is the correct method of creating a measurement for a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct way is to use Set() method with the measurement class as the object parameter.